# Homework about binary trees

Tags: java, binary-tree

Hello everyone i have a question about my homework.

This is my question:Complete the following method so that it will return true if the trees pointed to by the parameter node1 and node2 are equal.

This is my answer:

```
` public static boolean treeEqual(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2) {
        if (node1.key == node2.key && node1.left == null && node2.left == null && node1.right == null && node2.right == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (node1 == null || node2 == null) {
                return false;

            } else {
                boolean f = false;
                boolean y = false;
                if (node2.left != null && node1.left != null && node1.right != null && node1.key != node2.key || node1.key == node2.key) {


                    TreeNode ptrleft1 = node1.left;
                    TreeNode ptrright1 = node1.right;
                    TreeNode ptrleft2 = node2.left;
                    TreeNode ptrright2 = node2.right;
                    if (ptrleft1.key == ptrleft2.key && ptrleft1.left == ptrleft2.left && ptrleft1.right == ptrleft2.right) {
                        f = true;

                        treeEqual(ptrright1, ptrright2);
                    } else {
                        f = false;
                    }
                    if (ptrright1.key == ptrright2.key && ptrright1.left == ptrright2.left && ptrright1.right == ptrright2.right) {
                        y = true;
                        treeEqual(ptrright1, ptrright2);
                    } else {
                        y = false;
                    }
                }
                if (f == true && y == true) {
                    f = true;
                } else {
                    f = false;
                }


                return f;
            }
            }
        }`
```

This code is not working this is my error:

An exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException was reported when executing 
this line:

```
if (node1.key== node2.key&& node1.left == null && node2.left == null && node1.right == null && node2.right == null) {
```

but in intellij this is working, i don't understand where is the problem.

### 1. question 1 is fixed now working

2. This is my question: **Complete the following method so that it returns a pointer to the node containing the largest data value in the tree pointed to by the parameter ptr, or null if ptr points to an empty tree:**

**this is my code:**

```
    if (ptr == null) {
            return ptr;
        } else {
            TreeNode ptrright = ptr.right;
            TreeNode ptrleft = ptr.left;
            if (ptrright != null && ptrleft != null&&ptr!=null) {
                TreeNode ptrrightmax = ptrToMax(ptrright);
                TreeNode ptrleftmax = ptrToMax(ptrleft);
                if (ptr.data> ptrrightmax.data&& ptr.data> ptrleftmax.data) {
                    return ptr;
                } else {
                    if (ptrrightmax.data> ptrleftmax.data&&ptrrightmax.data>ptr.data) {
                      return ptrrightmax ;
                    } else {
if(ptrleftmax.data>ptrrightmax.data&&ptrleftmax.data>ptr.data)
                      return ptrleftmax ;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return ptr
```

i do not understand what is a problem? where is my wrong

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i have need to answer about this question is specific System, but in this System i got some error for example: if (node1.key== node2.key&& node1.left == null && node2.left == null && node1.right == null && node2.right == null) {
This will happen if you try to access a member or method of a variable whose value is null. but when i run it in intellij it is work.

Comment: An exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException was reported when executing this line: if (node1.key== node2.key&& node1.left == null && node2.left == null && node1.right == null && node2.right == null)  sorry i forgot to write it

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
if (node2.left != null && node1.left != null && node1.right != null && node1.key != node2.key || node1.key == node2.key) {
```

Change that to add also && node2.right != null

```
if (node2.left != null && node1.left != null && node1.right != null && node2.right != null && node1.key != node2.key || node1.key == node2.key) {
```

Due to that, you were calling the method treeEqual with a null value when node2.right was null, which caused the null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you, i change it but is stil same error     An exception of type java.lang.NullPointerException was reported when executing this line:

    if (node1.data== node2.data&& node1.left == null && node2.left == null && node1.right == null && node2.right == null) {

Comment: I think perhaps your code example is missing some lines, cause I can't see this line there.

Comment: i attached file in descripiton

Comment: thanks, I believe then the issue is perhaps a unit test that calls me method treeEqual(null, null). What you could do is move the following block to the beginning of the method: if (node1 == null || node2 == null) {
                return false;

            }